# Android WebView открывает пустую ссылку при переходе из другого приложения

Tags: android, android-studio, android-webview

У меня есть рабочее приложение браузер. Оно определяется системой, как браузер и может быть установлено, как приложение по умолчанию. При нажатии на ссылку в каком-либо приложении (предположим в почте), открывается мой браузер, но в заголовке ничего не написано и экран с сайтом пуст. А, если нажать на кнопку "скопировать ссылку" (рабочая кнопка, проверял), то скопируется пустой текст. Также, отмечу то, что в лэйауте на месте названия сайта написано слово "text", а при открытии ссылки просто пусто, значит он меняет название сайта, но почему то на пустоту, а не тот, который был нажат.

Теперь подробнее про код. Есть 3 класса и 2 лэйаута:

1. MainActivity.java связан с одноименным layout на котором помещена одна кнопка, при нажатии на которую интентом передается ссылка google.com в класс Browser.java
2. Browser.java класс связанный с content_browser.xml. Тут и происходит работа всего браузера. Может именно тут можно что-то сделать, чтобы ссылки открывались. Дело в том, что если ссылка передана из интента, то все открывается, но метода для перехвата ссылки из другого приложения я не знаю.
3. WebClient.java наследует WebViewClient и имеет лишь один метод. Возможно и тут надо что-то сделать чтобы все заработало. Дело в том что в Browser.java есть такая строка:

```
web.setWebViewClient(new WebClient());
```

Как вы понимаете я сам плохо разбираюсь в теме WebView, в доках указано, что
shouldOverrideUrlLoading() должен решать эту проблему, но он у меня есть в двух классах, а каких-то других методов для работы с ссылками из других приложений я не нашел.

Код:
MainActivity.java: https://pastebin.com/EMdQ4g8G

Browser.java до того места, где можно найти ошибки: https://pastebin.com/RDKqfwRR

WebClient.java: https://pastebin.com/LgteTV4i

Comment: У Вас не так много кода - для наглядности лучше опубликуйте его здесь.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Дело в том, что приложения указывают адрес не через экстра, как Вы, а через data:

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Browser.class);
    intent.setData(Uri.parse("https://www.google.com"));
    startActivity(intent);
  ----------------------------------------------------------------

    webView.loadUrl(getIntent().getDataString());
```

А класс `WebClient` в таком виде Вам вообще не нужен, можете установить дефолтный:

```
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
```